# python3 plotly timeline gant diagram customdata for every bar

Tags: python, plotly, visualization

I am trying to use dash + plotly to create a horizontal time line diagram.
Several actors are working on shared resources in some time slots.
I would like to visualize with horizontal bars work process of every actor.
But in the hover on each horizontal bar I would like to see the resource that this actor is working on in this timeslot.

For example:

actor1 working on resource1 from 08:00:00 to 10:30:00
actor2 working on resource1 from 10:00:00 to 10:40:00
actor1 working on resource2 from 10:31:00 to 11:00:00
actor3 working on resource3 from 09:15:00 to 10:15:00

I represented it in the following data sample :

```
data_sample = {
        'Actor': ['actor1', 'actor2', 'actor1', 'actor3'],
        'Start Time': ['08:00:00', '10:00:00', '10:31:00', '09:15:00'],
        'End Time': ['10:30:00', '10:40:00', '11:00:00', '10:15:00'],
        'Resource': ['resource1', 'resource1', 'resource2', 'resource3']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data_sample)
df['Start Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Time'])
df['End Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End Time'])
```

And trying to visualise in following way:

```
fig = px.timeline(df, x_start='Start Time', x_end='End Time', y='Actor', color='Actor')
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate='Resource: %{customdata}<br>' +
                                'Start Time: %{base}<br>' +
                                'End Time: %{x}<br>',
                   customdata=df['Resource'])

app.layout = html.Div([dcc.Graph(figure=fig)])
```

I can see a pretty beautiful picture.  The only problem that I accidentally noticed and can figure out how to deal with it it the wrong hovers. For example, diagram shows that actor3 is working on resource1 but not on resource3.
Looks like customdata in update_traces starts from the very beginning for every actor.
But I need it to match the appropriate index of the 'Actor' frame.

[image: wrong hover for actor3]

How can I deal with it? May be I could prepare data in another format? Or use another type of diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished by setting custom data directly in the express timeline.

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.timeline(df,
                  x_start='Start Time',
                  x_end='End Time',
                  y='Actor',
                  color='Actor',
                  custom_data='Resource')
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate='Resource: %{customdata}<br>' +
                                'Start Time: %{base}<br>' +
                                'End Time: %{x}<br>',
                  #customdata=[[x] for x in df['Resource']]
                 )
fig.show()
```

[image]